# Convert nodes that consists of nested objects, strings, array into an unordered list (Javascript)

Tags: javascript, html

I have this variable value of
 `["test", { testone: "check", filter: [{ testtwo: "ignore", cancel: ["3.2"]}]}, "testthree"].`

What I want to do is to display this in an unordered list below.

```
 . test
   . check
       . ignore
         . 3.2
 . testthree
```

I can convert it to a list if its in an array or array object, nested kinda confused me. I am thinking that a recursive function (correct me if i am wrong) can be used here and this is my first time solving a complex problem with javascript, care to share some sample how to solve this? Thanks

Comment: "testthree" occurs at an invalid position in your literal. The closing brace after it should come before it.

Comment: A tiny bit of research gives you plenty of starting points. https://www.google.com/search?q=javascript+create+nested+ul+from+object+site%3Astackoverflow.com

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is a recursive function to produce a nested `ul` element. For the example data, there will be a sublist whose only item is a deeper list, and so you see two list bullets next to eachother. This is where the sample data has an array with one object-element -- without any "label".

```js
function toUnorderedList(arr) {
    const ul = document.createElement("ul");
    let li = document.createElement("li");
    for (const value of Object.values(arr)) {
        if (Object(value) !== value) { // Primitive value
            li = document.createElement("li");
            li.textContent = value;
        } else { // Object (maybe Array)
            li.append(toUnorderedList(value));
        }
        ul.append(li);
    }
    return ul;
}

const data = [
    "test", 
    { 
        testone: "check", 
        filter: [
            { testtwo: "ignore", cancel: ["3.2"] }
        ], 
    },
    "testthree"
];

document.body.append(toUnorderedList(data));
```